# Using Regex to exclude all folders and files that contains "cache" in the Appdata folder from Crashplan backup

Tags: regex, windows, backup, directory

Basically I want to exclude cache folders and files from Crashplan backups using their regex exclusions and create other exclusions based on the solution to this.

Files like these:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\iconcache_16.db
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Spotify\Browser\ChromeDWriteFontCache
```

and folders like these

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice\4\user\uno_packages\cache
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash\CacheWritableAdobeRoot\AssetCache
```

This is what I came up with using [Crashplans basic instructions](https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Configuring/Excluding_Or_Filtering_Files_Using_File_Type_And_Regular_Expressions) and no real regex knowledge:

```
(?i)/AppData/.*/*cache*/*.*
```

It doesn't seem to do the trick however, I'm guessing I'm missing something with the subfolders.

This works fine for specific folders I want something that covers multiple ones:

```
.*/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Media Cache/.*
```

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction so it can check in any and all subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
(?i)\/AppData\/.*?cache.*?$
```

Comment: Please explain why it resolves the issue. This answer was flagged for Low Quality because it's so short.

Comment: That seems to work for cache files and folders in the appdata folder only, not with the stuff several folders deep like the examples above.